# How to integrate Google Cloud Identity with classic username/password authorization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

I am looking for a solution to integrate **Google Cloud Identity** into an existing project. The idea is that there are two applications - old and new one. Within old application the users are right now logging with username and password, within the new one I plan to introduce GCI.

Is there any way to have **backward compatibility with the old application authorization model** while having already Cloud Identity established in the new app?

The problem is that user is supposed to be able to authorize both in old and new applications and I can't think of a solution that would not force me to change authorization model in the old application which I would really prefer not to.

Answer (score 1):

After thorough research I came to a conclusion that the best way to integrate classic authorization by username and password with Google Cloud Identity would be thanks to **Firebase**.

Firebase Authentication supports password authentication in addition to federated sign in with Google, Facebook, Twitter, and more, allowing you to easily scale your authentication system as you grow on desktop and mobile. Apart from that Firebase is also provided out of box when using Google Cloud Platform.

Using Firebase I will be able to implement simple login with username and password in the old app and use Google Sign In within the new app.